# How to load image if the image is available on AWS?

Tags: javascript, html, vuejs2

I upload image from vue, to server. The server will return the image url, but it's will process the image first, and then upload it to AWS. And the process may takes about 1 - 3 second untill the image fully uploaded to AWS

The problem is my vue already get the image url before the image fully upload, and try to load it in `<img>`, and an error happen, 404 not found. Because it's not fully uploaded to AWS.

Question:
How to automatically load an image as soon as the image available on AWS using best practice / clean way?

For now, I use looping, and use @error, and check every 1 second. But I think it's not clean

Comment: Show a loader while img is not available.

Comment: @Grumpy But How to know when the image is available?

Comment: I don't think you can do anything more. On error re-check url. Just have re-tries counter to not make it infinite. Also you can do incremental re-check. E.g. `retries * 150ms`